# Trying to make a planner with repeat function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a planner in vue.js with a repeat function. I'm now trying to duplicate 1 planning item that will change if I make changes to the original and the other way around.

```
const getters = {
    // Return all items from expanded users in the team grid
    TEAMGRIDITEMS: (state, getters) => {

        // Filter all undefined values from the items array
        state.items = state.items.filter(function (item) {

            // Return all items that aren't undefined
            return item !== undefined;
        });

        try {
            return _.chain(state.items)
                // Filter items
                .filter(function (item) {

                        // Check if the userId matches the item id
                        let isExpanded = getters.EXPANDEDUSERS.includes(item.userId);

                        if (!isExpanded || item === undefined)
                            return false;

                        // Obtain index of the item
                        let itemIndex = moment(item.startDate).diff(moment(getters.STARTDATE).startOf('isoWeek'), 'days');

                        // Obtain the endindex of a item
                        let endIndex = moment(item.endDate).diff(moment(item.startDate), 'days') + 1;

                        // Obtain the max index for the displayadble amount of weeks
                        let maxIndex = moment(getters.STARTDATE).diff(moment(getters.ENDDATE).startOf('isoWeek'), 'days');

                        // Is the index higher than 0 and equal or less than the max index (abs to convert to positive)?
                        if (itemIndex + endIndex >= 0 && itemIndex <= Math.abs(maxIndex)) {
                            item.index = itemIndex;
                        }

                        // Is the index > or equal to 0 and the index < the maxIndex
                        return itemIndex + endIndex >= 0 && itemIndex <= Math.abs(maxIndex);
                    }
                )
                // Map results and add grid required properties
                .map(function (item) {

                    // The width of a single item in the day navigation bar
                    let staticTopBarWidth = 51;

                    // Check amount of days a item contains
                    let days = moment(item.endDate).diff(moment(item.startDate), 'days') + 1;

                    // Replace with a store saved date
                    let width = days * 51;

                    // Calculate the grid required properties for the item
                    item.leftDistancePX = item.index * staticTopBarWidth;
                    item.leftDistanceInitPX = item.index * staticTopBarWidth;
                    item.widthPX = width;

                    // Return item
                    return item;
                })
                .value();

        } catch (e) {
        }
    },
```

[image: image of vue devtools]

How can I duplicate one of these that will change it's `startdate`, `enddate` etc when I change the original?